# steps to get a Mac to report CPU and memory load via SNMP?

Tags: macos, memory, cpu, snmp

My group runs a bunch of Mac Pros and xServes of various flavors, and being a fairly recent hire, I am getting up to speed on how to monitor them properly. We use SolarWinds NPM and SAM, and monitor those Macs via SNMP.

Problem: some of them do not report CPU and memory load, and one - volumes.

snmp configurations on these are identical.

Is this about MIBs? What's the easiest way to get all of our Macs to report CPU and memory load?

Say, I have two xServes (OSX 10.6.8 but it doesn't really matter); one is reporting CPU/mem, the other one isn't. snmpd.conf files are identical. What do I need to do to enable CPU/mem polling on the handicapped machine? Is this about copying certain MIBs in /usr/share/snmp from one machine to another?

Thanks!

Comment: I needed to compare snmpd executables (/use/sbin/snmpd if memory serves me right) - and they were different. Once the handicapped one was replaced with the stock version, almost everything started behaving as it should.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you can use laLoadInt to get processor load, and hrMemorySize and related MIBS to get memory metrics.  However, my experience is that on Mac OS (at least, on 10.8.5), snmpd was compiled without kmem, because apparently apple doesn't support the calls.  I am amazed that Apple would simply remove this feature, but it appears that they decided we could live without it.

Anyway, even on my 10.8.5 system, I can get 1, 5, and 15-minute processor load averages with the OID laLoadInt.<1 2 or 3>

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the answer - even though it doesn't answer the question. The answer to my question was, someone recompiled snmpd executable, and it was thus not responding to certain SNMP requests.